# Extract VOSUB from MP4

Tags: video, mp4, subtitle

First of all, this is a question regarding videos (and 0 programming). I have seen some posts where people have got comments about not posting such questions here, while there's no such comment on some other posts. If it's in a wrong place, let me know where else I can post this question.

The question:

I have got a few MP4 files which have soft-coded DVD Subtitles. I'd like to extract those subtitles in any possible format.

Had it been MKV, I'd have used MKVCleaver, had the subtitles been simple SRT kinda, I'd have used FFMPEG, but, there doesn't seem any way to extract DVDSUB from MP4.

I tried converting the video (with subtitles) to MKV (-c:v copy -c:s copy -c:a copy), but, that didn't work. I tried just changing the extension to MKV. VLC could play it, but, MKVCleaver denied that to be MKV format (was kinda obvious).

So, I'd just like to know what I can do to seperate the subtitles file from the video.

Here's a screenshot of the codec information VLC displays:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have a look here - some comment confirms worked for mp4: https://superuser.com/a/927507

Comment: @Mick It doesn't work for VOSUB.